# Using 'You' or 'I' in Forms

Tags: pronouns, formality

Which one of the following is better/more common/more widely accepted, when writing a form to be filled out as part of a survey?

Option 1:

> Q1. My preferred investment option: ________ (list of choices)
>
> Q2. I am a: _______ (list of choices (businessperson, student, etc.))
>
> Q3. I invest ___% of my income in FDs/CDs

Option 2:

> Q1. What is your preferred investment option? ________ (list of choices)
>
> Q2. You are a: _______ (list of choices (businessperson, student, etc.))
>
> Q3. I invest ___% of my income in FDs/CDs

Comment: You could also go the impersonal route with *Preferred colour: __*. Whichever you choose doesn't really matter, but you should stick with a single style. That is, don't do this: *1. My preferred colour __ 2. What is your favourite food? __*

Comment: Could you actually use the term/s you are will be using on your form? "Color" just encourages a sort of lackadaisical approach, as if  somehow it's not worthy of proper attention because of its childish connotations, whereas it shouldn't make any difference but...it does.

Comment: My favorite food is baby elephant in classic marinara sauce with Belgian beer. Just so you know.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Edited.

Comment: Now the *preferred* makes sense, there is a choice/list (Hey, I'm no expert in making up online surveys) But what has "you" or "I" got to do with it? You mean **my preferred** vs **your preferred**

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on the milieu.

"My" is preferable if you're surveying penniless guttersnipes, whilst "your" might be more palatable with the idle stinking rich 1-percenters.

"Preferred" is wrong: you should say "favorite": kids really dig it: favorite this and favorite that. Also works with people who refuse to grow up.

Some grouchy types might object, which is why you might want to consider using "annoys you the least" instead of "favorite."

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot, beforehand, know whether my respected surveyee is a gutless penny-swipe or a stinky rich idol because the survey comprises the very same question (though it is worded to classify into a few income groups rather than two socioeconomic ones).

Comment: @shardulc Then you should stick with "my" and hope for the best. I just don't like the question. I mean, if a person says their favorite color is mauve, what can you possibly deduce from that? Or, a lot of leaves in the summer are a subtle blend of indigo and lemon yellow: but what kind of person would write that in a survey form? The question is ambiguous. Some people like it, especially women, but that's not because they're artists or anything.

Comment: Nice to see you back here.